# Error inflating class fragment Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i want to transfer data from activity to fragment but i get "Error inflating class fragment" I have searched for solution for that problem but still can't.

this is my full code of **FirstFragment.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [FirstFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private lateinit var communicator: Communicator
    private lateinit var myTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        myTextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.profile_name_text) as TextView

        // Gets the data from the passed bundle
        val bundle = arguments
        val message = bundle!!.getString("mText")

        // Sets the derived data (type String) in the TextView
        myTextView.text = message
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment FirstFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            FirstFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

my function at **Home.kt**

```
fun getData() {
    val mFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val mFragment = FirstFragment()
    val mBundle = Bundle()
    val testText = "My Name is Jack"
    mBundle.putString("mText",testText)
    mFragment.arguments = mBundle
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, mFragment).commit()
}
```

at the **fragment_first.xml** i want to put the text into the TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_Layout_home_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue_shape"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_name_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nama_pengguna"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/cloudy"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this is code of **activity_home.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Please attach code for `fragment_first.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on documentation:

> Note: when manually calling setGraph() with arguments, you must not use the app:navGraph attribute when creating the NavHostFragment in XML as that will internally call setGraph() without any arguments, resulting in your graph and start destination being created twice.

[docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start)

You've already defined `app: navGraph` on your activity(Fragment Container) so you can't call `navController. SetGraph` from java/kotlin.
Try with remove `app:navGraph` from Fragment Container

Comment: I tried it and it worked, apparently I defined it twice.
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data using fragment constructor like this:

```
fun getData() {

   val mFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
   val mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   val testText = "My Name is Jack"
   val mFragment = FirstFragment(testText)
   mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, mFragment).commit()
}
```

And fetch it in the fragment like this:

```
class FirstFragment(private val someText: String): Fragment() {

    private lateinit var myTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        myTextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.profile_name_text) as TextView

        // Sets the derived data (type String) in the TextView
        myTextView.text = someText
        return view
    }
}
```

Also seeing your **fragment_first.xml** layout, you might wanna put it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nama_pengguna"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/cloudy"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still with the same error, but now it appears "could not find Fragment constructor"
and when I click on the blue error description (Home.kt:28) it leads to the line "setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused your issue. But noticed you are using Jetpack navigation.

And you're trying to pass data to the start destination of the graph.

Here is an official doc for dealing with your case:
[Pass data to the start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start).

And below are some of the code I tried myself, just for your reference:

I think in your MainActivity.kt, you would have something like this:

```
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.my_nav, Bundle().apply {
            putString("name", "My name is xx")
        })
```

And in the first fragment, retrieve the parameter:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val name = arguments?.get("name")
        Log.w("xx", "$name")
```

Edit: I updated the `findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)` and `navController.setGraph(R.navigation.my_nav` according to the ids in your code.

Comment: no error occurs but the data received is null "W/xx: null"

Comment: Pls make sure your navigation graph is `nav_graph`, which is used in this statement: `navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph`, if it is not, update it according to your real case. And make sure this: `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)`, read from your code, yours is `fragmentContainerView`.

Comment: actually i've been doing that since the beginning you have a solution, but when it gives a String data type("My name is xx"), the data received is null.

Comment: ScreenShoot : https://ibb.co/wBT5Qsj

Comment: the screenshot helps. Can you post the screenshot for activity_home.xml /  my_nav.xml / fragment_first.xml / FirstFragment.kt?

Comment: activity_home.xml (https://ibb.co/ryBtyqb)
my_nav.xml (https://ibb.co/KbLxGGM)
fragment_first.xml (https://ibb.co/pxTTXzD)
FragmentFirst.kt (https://ibb.co/s3tsjH3)

Comment: In your FragmentFirst.kt L33, your code is `arguments?.get("names")`. Double check the key that you put into bundle in your activity when `navController.setGraph(R.navigation.my_nav, Bundle().apply {
            putString("name", "My name is xx")
        })`

Comment: ahh, i'm sorry for doing too much experiment i forgot about that but after i change it to "names" the data get still null,
https://ibb.co/6PYQMg9

Comment: there is a warning in L113: fun getData(). I was doubt whether it gets called...

Comment: i have called it in onCreate home.kt, my problem is solved, it turns out that i defined app:navGraph in activity_home.xml(Fragment Container), and i also defined it in my_nav.xml its resulting in my graph and start destination being created twice.
Thanks alot for you Mr.LiuWenBin_NO, You really have helped me a lot